# Tranmission line equations when initial conditions are not zero

Tags: high-voltage, transmission-line

A high voltage DC line is in steady state sufficiently long time after applying 1 MV at the input terminals through a DC voltage source of 30 ohm impedance with an open circuit at the load end. The characterstic impedance of the line is 20 ohms. The line length is 1000 Km. The line capacitance is 0.2 nF/m. The line may be treated as lossless.
To this charged line a 30 ohm load is connected at t=0 . Find an expression for the voltage on the line after t = 0 at various points on the line with usual labeling : position of sending end is –L and load end position is 0 and any arbitrary location is –
I cam across this question my college assignment, I couldn't solve it any suggestions how to solve it? Any reference material?

Comment: Its a solution of a telegraph equation with initial conditions

Comment: At the load, the line looks like a Thevenin source with a voltage of 1 MV and an impedance of 20 ohms. What happens when you throw a 30-ohm load across this source? How does this disturbance propagate down the line? Solving this is no different from solving the multiple reflections in any other line after the first one.

Comment: @Dave So now how do we calculate the initial value, I know that we can solve by using bounce diagram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial conditions are that the 20 Ω line is charged to 1 MV, and at t=0 you connect a 30 Ω load.

The immediate effect is that the line and the load form a voltage divider, so the terminal voltage at the load end immediately becomes 600 kV. This -400 kV step is the initial disturbance that propagates back up the line toward the source.

Both the source impedance and the load impedance are 30 Ω, so the [reflection coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_coefficient) is the same at both ends:

$$\Gamma = \frac{Z_T - Z_0}{Z_T + Z_0} = \frac{30 \Omega - 20 \Omega}{30 \Omega + 20 \Omega} = 0.2$$

At the source, the initial -400 kV step is reflected as a -400 × 0.2 = -80 kV step, bringing the line to 520 kV.

At the load, this step is reflected as an additional -80 × 0.2 = -16 kV step, bringing the line to 504 kV.

The next steps are 500.8 kV, 500.16 kV and 500.032 kV.

After a large number of steps, the line voltage converges on 500 kV, just as you'd expect. In the steady state, you have a simple voltage divider between the source impedance and the load impedance.

So now we know what happens, but how fast does it happen?

Knowing the capacitance allows us to also calculate the line's inductance from its [characteristic impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_impedance#Lossless_line):

$$Z_0 = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}$$

so,

$$L = Z_0^2 C = 20^2 0.2nF/m = 80nH/m$$

Knowing both of these values allows us to calculate the [velocity factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_factor#Calculating_velocity_factor) for a lossless line:

$$VF = \frac{1}{c \sqrt{L C}} = \frac{1}{3\cdot10^8 \sqrt{0.2 nF \cdot 80 nH}} = 0.8333$$

Those two formulas can be combined into a simpler formula that gives the same answer:

$$VF = \frac{1}{c Z_0 C}$$

Knowing this, plus the length of the line, allows you to calculate the time between the reflections.